# Drag and Drop issue in Rally Grid

Tags: javascript, rally, appsdk2

I have an issue in my recent implemented Rally Grid.

```
_CreatePSIObjectiveGrid: function(myStore) {
    if (!this.objGrid) {
        var colCfgs = [{
            text: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'DragAndDropRank',
            width: 50
        }, {
            text: 'Summary',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Success Rate',
            dataIndex: 'c_SuccessRate',
            width: 200
        }];

        if (!this.getSetting("useSuccessRatioOnly")) {
            colCfgs.push({
                text: 'Initial Business Value',
                dataIndex: 'PlanEstimate',
                width: 200
            });

            colCfgs.push({
                text: 'Final Business Value',
                dataIndex: 'c_FinalValue',
                width: 200
            });
        }

        this.objGrid = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
            store : myStore,
            enableRanking: true,
            defaultSortToRank: true,
            height: 550,
            overflowY: 'auto',
            margin: 10,
            showPagingToolbar: false,
            columnCfgs : colCfgs
        });

        Ext.getCmp('c-panel-obj-crud-table').add(this.objGrid);
    }
}
```

Although I have set "enableRanking" to "true", the ranking drag and drop doesn't work if I add my grid to a component. However, the drag and drop function does work perfectly if I change the last statement from

```
Ext.getCmp('c-panel-obj-crud-table').add(this.objGrid);
```

to

```
this.add(this.objGrid);
```

I don't know if this is a Rally bug. Try to compare the final html file generated, no clue is found.

Answer (score 0):

[this few sec video shows](http://screencast.com/t/4b9YWQzSK08) that the code below, where a rankable grid is added to a child panel, and not directly to `this` (`this` points to the app's global scope) still preserves its ability to rerank:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout: 'hbox',
            itemId: 'parentPanel',
            componentCls: 'panel',
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Panel 1',
                width: 600,
                itemId: 'childPanel1'
                },
                {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Panel 2',
                width: 600,
                itemId: 'childPanel2'
                }
            ],
        });
        this.add(panel);
        this.down('#childPanel1').add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            columnCfgs: [
                'FormattedID',
                'Name',
                'ScheduleState',
                'Owner'
            ],
            context: this.getContext(),
            enableRanking: true,
            defaultSortToRank: true,
            storeConfig: {
                model: 'userstory'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If the example works, it could be an issue for tabbed Panel. In my case, I have a tabbed panel and then a panel inside this. I want to add the ranked grid into the child panel inside a tabbed panel. I also did some further investigation on the issue. It seems the drag operation does work. However, the drop zone is not valid.